# Retrieve id using multiple value From Firebase

Tags: firebase

I want to retrieve item id and get it to variable using items other value. according to this image ("get id where Brand="Manchee" and ItemName="Cream Cracker" and SubCategory="100g" ")
how write this function

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Query based on multiple where clauses in Firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26700924/query-based-on-multiple-where-clauses-in-firebase)

Answer (score 0):

Here you can try this solution.I think you wanted to query the database so you can fire query on your database based on your variable value.Just pass the key and value in this query and you can have all the data reside in the table which falls within this query.

```
  var ref = firebase.database().ref("items");
    ref.orderByChild("itemName").equalTo('Manchee').once("value", (items : any)=> {
      console.log(items.key);
      console.log(items.val());
      let itemArray: any = [];

      items.forEach((item) => {
        itemArray.push({
          key: item.key,

        });
      });
      this.items = itemArray;
      console.log("Prescription Data: ", itemArray);
    });
```